# python-pptx: insert picture into content placeholder

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm using python-pptx 0.6.0 and I created a slide with content with caption.
I want to insert picture into the content placeholder but there is no attribute such as add_picture or insert_picuture to use.
How can I add picture into this content placeholder?
Thanks for answering my question :)

Answer (score 6):

See the documentation on [Understanding placeholders](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/placeholders-understanding.html) and [Working with placeholders](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/placeholders-using.html).

In brief, using something like this, you get the placeholder from the slide, then call `insert_picture` on the placeholder:

```
>>> prs = Presentation()
>>> slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[8])
>>> placeholder = slide.placeholders[1]  # idx key, not position
>>> placeholder.name
'Picture Placeholder 2'
>>> placeholder.placeholder_format.type
PICTURE (18)
>>> picture = placeholder.insert_picture('my-image.png')
```

Note that this only works with a picture placeholder. You'll need to replace any "general purpose" content placeholder with one specific to what you're going to insert.