# python-pptx: insert picture into placeholder but get error

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I want to insert the plot I created into the power point with `insert_picture()`.
I searched from online and found info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744260/python-pptx-insert-picture-into-content-placeholder).

I create a simple figure as below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

And I use `python-pptx` to create a power point.

```
graph_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(graph_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
title.text = "Test"
placeholder = slide.placeholders[1]
pic = placeholder.insert_picture(fig)
prs.save('Desktop\test.pptx')
```

However, I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'SlidePlaceholder' object has no attribute 'insert_picture'
```

There is a note I found [here](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/placeholders-using.html#placeholders-using).

```
Note
A reference to a picture placeholder becomes invalid after its insert_picture() method is called. 
This is because the process of inserting a picture replaces the original p:sp XML element with a new p:pic element containing the picture. 
Any attempt to use the original placeholder reference after the call will raise AttributeError. 
The new placeholder is the return value of the insert_picture() call and may also be obtained from the placeholders collection using the same idx key.
```

After that, I changed the code to:

```
graph_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[8]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(graph_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
title.text = "Test"
placeholder = slide.placeholders[1]
pic = placeholder.insert_picture(fig)
prs.save('Desktop\test.pptx')

placeholder.name
'Picture Placeholder 2'
placeholder.placeholder_format.type
18
```

I got another error:

```
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
You should save the figure first and use the save plot.

```
fig.save('test')

pic = placeholder.insert_picture('test.png')
```